# possible code optimizations while using JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have following `JSONArray` object from a jsonobject key `"elements"`

```
[ {
    "id":"as-a-user,-i-should-be-able-to-navigate",
      "elements":[  

    {
        "id": "navigate-down",    
        "type":"scenario"
    }
    ,
    {
        "id": "navigate-up",
        "type":"scenario"
    }
    ,
    {
        "id": ";eating",
        "examples":[ {
            "id": "as-a-user,-i-should-be-able-to-navigate;eating;", "description":"", "name":"", "keyword":"Examples", "line":23, "rows":[ {
                "id": "eating;;1", "cells": ["start", "eat", "left"], "line": 24
            }
            ,
            {
                "id": "eating;;2", "cells": ["12", "5", "7"], "line": 25
            }
            ,
            {
                "id": "eating;;3", "cells": ["20", "5", "15"], "line": 26
            }
            ]
        }
        ],
        "type":"scenario_outline"
    }
    ]
}

]
```

Here is the code i used to find the "rows" key details in the above JSON array.Am getting the row key values using the below code.My code using lots of 
`JSONObjects` and `JSONArrays` to get data.I have to do some code optimizations .How can i simplyfy my code.any better solutions?

code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = convertFileToJSON();
            JSONArray elementsArray= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("elements");        
            for(int i = 0; i < elementsArray.size(); i++)
            {
                  JSONObject objects = (JSONObject) elementsArray.get(i);                
                  if(objects.get("keyword").equals("scenario_outline")){
                      JSONArray elementsArray1= (JSONArray) objects.get("examples"); 
                      JSONObject objects1 = (JSONObject) elementsArray1.get(0);                 
                      JSONArray rowArray= (JSONArray) objects1.get("rows");
                      System.out.println(rowArray.size());

                  }

            }
```

Comment: *"I have to do some code optimizations ."* why? what problems do you have that you need to do *optimizations*?

Answer (score 1):

Optimization is a program transformation technique, which tries to improve the code by making it consume less resources (i.e. CPU, Memory) and deliver high speed. (Ref: tutorials point)

Your code is perfect, not to say if that is exactly the correct form you required but in the context of memory allocations.

Honestly, your code is neat and clean. You probably do not require any changes for optimisation.